# GPU not detecting after dual boot in ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, nvidia, gpu

After running the command :

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

I don't get the name of my Graphics Card which is nvidia Gtx 1650 Ti.

After running the command:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Dell Device 09e1
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f95 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 09e1
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
```

This is the output.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Please add output of `sudo apt update`. If you are behind a proxy, you'll need to setup `apt` to be usable.

Answer (score 1):

The device is too new for `ubuntu-drivers` installed in 20.04.

Anyway you can install Nvidia drivers by

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515
```

Comment: Getting error as: 403 Forbidden IP.Also I tried to install it from the GUI but got the error of pk-client-error-quark restricted amd64 libnvidia

Comment: This is a different problem. You are behind some firewall that doesn't let to connect to Ubuntu repositories.